# doesnt work in ng-repeat in angularJS why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, video.js

i use angular and video js, when i try to load my video:

```
 <div class="col-md-8" ng-repeat='season in show_detail.season_in_show|filter:seasonbyID'>
                                <div class="player-block" ng-show='hasSubscription(season)'>
                                    <video id="serial-video" class="video-js"  controls="controls" preload="auto" height="450" data-setup='' ng-src="{{season.preview_video}}">
                                        <source ng-src="{{season.preview_video}}"  controls="controls" type='video/mp4'>
                                    </video>
                                </div>
</div>
```

i get:
[image]

[image]

it happens only if i use ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping while div in another div which contains ng-if
make the statement true when all video data has loaded. Your issue could be with the face that dom is rendered before the data gets populated via videojs.

Edit:
I'm thinking that your 'season' variable gets populated dynamically. After your data population is done, set a variable for example $scope.dataArrived = true.
Then, perform:

```
<div ng-if="dataArrived">
//your dom code
</div>
```

Comment: I do not fully understand you, can you change my code in question?

Comment: I'm thinking that your 'season' variable gets populated dynamically. After your data population is done, set a variable for example $scope.dataArrived = true.